# want to add searchBook udpateBook deleteBook in linked list in java

Tags: java

```
package pro;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bookapp {
    static book head, pointer;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to SZABIST BOOK STORE");

        int choice = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. INSERT BOOK");
            System.out.println("2. DELETE BOOK");
            System.out.println("3. UDPATE BOOK");
            System.out.println("4. SEARCH BOOK");
            System.out.println("5. VIEW BOOK(S)");
            System.out.println("6. EXIT");

            System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
            try {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                addBook();
                break;
            case 2:
                deleteBook();
                break;
            case 3:
                udpateBook();
                break;
            case 4:
                searchBook();
                break;
            case 5:
                viewBook();
                break;
            case 6:
                input.close();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong Choice TRY AGAIN!");
            }

        } while (true);


    }

    private static void viewBook() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is EMPTY !");
        } else {
            pointer = head;
            for (book i = pointer; i != null; i = pointer.next) {
                System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }
        }

    }

    private static void searchBook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static void udpateBook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static void deleteBook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void addBook() {
        if (head == null) {
            String details[] = enterDetails();
            pointer = new book(details[0], details[1], details[2]);
            head = pointer;
            pointer.next = null;
        } else {
            String details[] = enterDetails();
            pointer.next = new book(details[0], details[1], details[2]);
            pointer = pointer.next;
            pointer.next = null;
        }

    }

    public static String[] enterDetails() {
        String[] details = new String[3];
        try {
            String title;
            String ISBN;
            System.out.print("Please enter Book Title: ");
            title = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please enter Book ISBN: ");
            ISBN = input.nextLine();

            String authors;
            System.out.print("Enter Book author(s): ");
            authors = input.nextLine();
            details[0] = title;
            details[1] = ISBN;
            details[2] = authors;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        return details;
    }

}

//class
package pro;

public class book {
    String[] authors;
    static String publisher;
    final String ISBN;
    final String title;
    book next;

    book(String title, String ISBN, String... authors){
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.title = title;
        this.authors = new String[authors.length];
        int i=0;
        for (String s: authors){
            this.authors[i]=s;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public String getBook(){
        return "BOOK TITLE: " + this.title + "\n" + "BOOK ISBN: " + this.ISBN + 
                "\n" + "BOOK AUTHOR(S):" + getAuthors() +"\n"
                ;
    }

    public String getAuthors(){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s1: this.authors){
            s.append(s1 + ",");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

}
```

want to add search Book update book delete Book in linked list in java
when i press 2 it update book
when i press 3 it search Book 
when i press 4 it delete book
In linked list in java.
cant find the way out

Comment: How do you _know_ _"when i press 2 it update book..."_ since those methods are currently empty.

Comment: Very good. What stops you?

Comment: you have an input variable, so why you are not using it??? how do you get input

Answer (score 0):

Call this with the book id to search from your search method.

```
private static void Book searchBook(int book_id) {
 if(head == null)
   return null;
 Book iterator = head;
 while(iterator != null){
  if(iterator.getId() == book_id){
   return iterator;
  }
  iterator = iterator.next;
 }
 return null;
}
```